# Print only part of a tuple in list

Tags: python, printing

I have this list:

```
                 Title             ,          Rating

 [('"$weepstake$" (1979) {(#1.2)}', '10.0'), 
  ('"\'Til Death Do Us Part" (2006) {Pilot (#1.0)}', '3.7'), 
  ('"\'Conversations with My Wife\'" (2010)', '4.2')]
```

how print the ratings like this:

```
 10
 3.7
 4.2
```

Comment: Try something, anything. If you can print each item in the list then it is *easy* to explain how to create a function (which can itself merely be an inline expression) such that it will achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each item in your list, you need the second item which is index `1`:

```
for item in your_list:
    print(item[1])
```

This will give you the desired output.

Comment: You mean `item[1]` right?

Comment: @JonClements Thank you I did, the sectioning if you know what I mean on the first strings confused me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
movies =  [('"$weepstake$" (1979) {(#1.2)}', '10.0'),   ('"\'Til Death Do Us Part" (2006) {Pilot (#1.0)}', '3.7'), 
  ('"\'Conversations with My Wife\'" (2010)', '4.2')]

print '\n'.join([movie[1] for movie in movies])
```